# R - MongoDB: Best way to store Dates inserted from R

Tags: r, mongodb, date

I would like to know what's the best way to store date and time objects in MongoDB. I don't mind what type, if POSIXct or POSIXlt or Date object.

I ask this question because I want an easy way to then query from R a range of dates, so that R only processes and plots those values.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

There are methods included in JavaScript like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778428/best-way-to-store-date-time-in-mongodb?rq=1), or by MongoDB itself, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764821/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-dates-in-mongodb?rq=1), but I would like to find an easy way to insert and then query it, all in R language, like "show me all the values between this range of dates".

Maybe the problem itself is how to organize it better when querying. Currently I have a running app that stores the time objects in the way of: (The comment is an example of the output)

```
as.character(strptime(Sys.time(), "%F %X"))
## 2015-01-01 12:00:00
```

But when I have to plot it, I get all the data in the collection. Then I process the dates inside a `ggplot()`, showing only the required dates.

This is very time-consuming and inefficient. I tried to perform a `$regex` to the MongoDB query, but that would make things so difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help:

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

Storing the data properly will speed up your query.

Also, what library are you using?  RmongoDB is ideal for speed and flexibility.

Then, you'll want to do a BSON query from within R on the data you want instead of requesting everything.

Comment: Thank you for the link! It will help a lot.

The only thing: I've been using rmongodb and rmongo (both outdated), but I've seen that the best option is to use mongolite https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mongolite/index.html that is currently being developed actively. You can see that rmongodb has been undeveloped for more than one year from now.

Comment: Thanks for that link!  It'll be nice to update to it.