# How to insert date in mongo DB without timezone

Tags: java, mongodb, rest

I am using  the following *date method* to insert a date in mongo DB:

```
BasicDBObject Created_Date = new BasicDBObject("date", now);
record.put("Created_Date", now);
```

It returns the result in below format:

```
 "Created_Date" : ISODate("2017-10-11T06:16:10.536Z")
```

Is it possible to insert date without time zone i.e.

```
"Created_Date" :"2017-10-11"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @glitch "MongoDB will not be able to tell whether `2017-10-11` is greater than `2017-10-10`." - Why not? Order of dates corresponds to order of strings.

Comment: Why don't you just convert date to string prior to saving?

Comment: @glitch: thanks but I want to insert current date and not the particular date like "2017-10-11" using ("Created_Date", now).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - Storing date without timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401231/mongodb-storing-date-without-timezone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not consistent with your example. Your example shows storing the date without the **time** portion of the date, but your question is about storing the date without the **timezone**.

MongoDB doesn't store timezone as part of the date, all dates are stored in UTC. See [Model Time Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/) for more details.

If you want to store the date without the time (as you show in your example), then "truncate" the date. You will still have a full Date object, with the time appearing as midnight UTC, but that's a fairly typical way of handling dates as you describe.

Since you're using Java, here are a few ways to truncate the date : [Java Date cut off time information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908387/java-date-cut-off-time-information)

Comment: even if I truncate the time to 00:00:00 still it converts that time to UTC time and stores in mongo

Comment: As I mentioned, you will still have a full Date object, with the time appearing as midnight UTC. The right thing to do is to properly format the dates in your application to show only the relevant portion. Furthermore, typically you would want to format all dates (regardless of if time is included) based on the User's timezone, since what constitutes a given "day" is dependent on your perspective of a given timezone.