# save only Date without timezone javascript

Tags: javascript

I am saving current date in mongodb with new Date(), But it is storing the date with the current time like below:

> ISODate("2018-12-04T13:34:03.510+05:30")

I want to save only the date with above format, **but without timezone for comparison purpose.** Please tell me how can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401231/mongodb-storing-date-without-timezone

Comment: not worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this package. This allows you to save dates in Mongo without having to worry about time zones shifting the date.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-dateonly

Answer (score 0):

You can save the date in the format of epoch time. And you can perform all kind of range queries on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date('2018-12-04T13:34:03.510+05:30')
var userTimezoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
new Date(date.getTime() - userTimezoneOffset);
```

Comment: Can you explain how this will solve OP's problem, please?