# Group by hour and count MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm on a project working with data of a bike-sharing service. Each trip has the following info

```
> db.bikes.find({bike:9990}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb59fd8e9fb374bf0cd5c1c"),
    "gender" : "M",
    "userAge" : 49,
    "bike" : 9990,
    "depStation" : 150,
    "depDate" : "01/08/2018",
    "depHour" : "0:00:13",
    "arrvStation" : 179,
    "arrvDate" : "01/08/2018",
    "arrvHour" : "0:23:38"
}
```

How do I group for each hour of the day and count the number of trips made in that specific hour?
I'm trying with this query

```
db.bikes.aggregate(
  { 
     $group:{_id:{$hour: "$depHour"}, trips:{$sum: 1}}
  }
)
```

But it throws this error

```
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type string to Date",
    "code" : 16006,
    "codeName" : "Location16006"
```

Comment: What are the possible values for the field `"depHour"`? What is its general time format, is it "h:mm:ss"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `depDate` and `depHour` fields are all string values that denote the day and the hour respectively so there is no need to use the [date operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-expression-operators) to convert the fields to date objects, all you need is to extract the hour part using **[`$substrCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrCP/#exp._S_substrCP)** and then use them directly as expressions in your `$group` `_id` as:

```
db.bikes.aggregate([
    { '$group': {
        '_id': {
            'day': '$depDate',
            'hour': { '$substrCP': [ '$depHour', 0, 2 ] }
        }, 
        'trips': { '$sum': 1 }
    } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked! Is it easier to handle data that way (day and hour separately) or using ISOdate for example?

Comment: A bit opinionated but this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764821/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-dates-in-mongodb) will enlighten you better, personally would go for the separate date and time string formats

Comment: Thanks! Also another question, using substring works when the hour value it's between 0 and 9 but since data it's in 24 hour format it doesn't work from 10-23. How can I handle this? Using regex?

Comment: From your example it doesn't look like 24-hr format (`"0:00:13"`) hence the questions I asked in the comments for the original question. My initial answer was based on the assumption that the hour part is the second token in the given format `0:hh:mm` i.e. the `00` part.. Obviously that was wrong but if it's indeed in the 24-hr format `hh:mm:ss` then `depHour` should read `00:00:13` instead of `0:00:13`. Nonetheless, the updated `{ '$substrCP': [ '$depHour', 0, 2 ] }` will handle the general 24-hr case although the hour part will be displayed as `0:` for 12 am or `9:` for 9 am, for example.

Comment: Yeah you're. right, Sorry, I just pasted in the first document the query gave me. I fixed it with split also the dataset has inconsistency handling times, as you said different hour formats(H:MM and HH:MM). Anyway your solution worked out for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation with mognodb **4.0**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$dateToString": {
        "date": {
          "$toDate": { "$concat": ["$depDate", "T", "$depHour"] }
        },
        "format": "%Y-%m-%d-%H"
      }
    },
    "trips": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

Comment: I believe this is overkill; there certainly is no need to convert the concatenated string to date object then back again to a string since the date strings already suffice. Apart from that the above won't give the correct results because the `_id` expression `{ "$dateToString: <expression> }` will always return `"YYY-MM-DD-00"`  as you forget there is always a `0` prefixed to `"$depHour"`

Comment: From my thinking that is not a prefix it is of format ("00:00:13")HH:MM:SS. So after converting to date it will be easier to `$group` with any desired format we want.

Comment: Actually you are right, the hour is the first digit but the format is `"h:mm:ss"`, not `"HH:mm:ss"` as you thought. I would still maintain the conversion can be a bit overkill though since you just need to extract the hour part and the day to get the group, otherwise you are right.

Comment: The main part here is the OP now can use `$group` with any format he/she wants. Your aggregation still doesn't work if the hours have two digits in it :-)