# GroupBy date + mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, group-by

I have to aggregate the result based on the month of the given document. Consider the following as my document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b3314a12b05b1b247366f48"),
    "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "qwerty":[{
            "id" : "5ba4ebbad1b5eaf038841302",
            "status" : "inprogress",           
            "Date" : "2018-08-20"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "5ba4ebbad1b5eaf038841303",
            "status" : "inprogress",           
            "Date" : "2018-08-20"
        }]
```

Following is my query:

```
var query =[
        { $match: {"email":email} },
        {$unwind: "$courses" },
        {$group:{_id:{$substrCP: ["$qwerty.Date", 5, 2]},count:{$sum:1}}}
    ];
```

Its working properly. But i `$substrCP: ["$qwerty.Date", 5, 2]` is based on the date format is "2018-08-20", what if "20-08-2018"?? So its possible to change the above query to accomodate of nay type.

Also i tried with new `Date("").getMonth()` but its showing as "NaN", i get to know that its not  possible to use inside group.

Please suggest your ideas.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by hour and count MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52639932/group-by-hour-and-count-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize [**$month**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) in combination with [**$dateFromString**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) to get what you need:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "email": "abc@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$qwerty"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $month: {
          $dateFromString: {
            dateString: "$qwerty.Date"
          }
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can [see it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e5NV31YBC9z) with the two different date formats.

To group per the date you can do the same without the `$month`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "email": "abc@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$qwerty"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$qwerty.Date"
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See this version [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cV2No6fHyqp)

Comment: Thanks its working.. But if i change `$month` to `$date`it  throwing error  `$date` is not recognised

Comment: Why would you do that? In your question you ware working with the month no?

Comment: I need for `month` ad `date` as separate aggregation query. For month its working perfectly with your post, but for date its not??