# How to store Date object data into string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

i am new in NodeJS and mongoDB, i created a variable of Date object when i prints its value it print this

`2021-08-06T00:00:00.000+00:00`

and stored in database in this format. But i want to store it like this `2021-08-06`. i try this way

```
var date = new Date().toISOString();
      date1 = date.substring(0, 10);
      console.log("date")
      console.log(date1);
```

its output is this

```
date
2021-08-06
```

and when i pass this variable into date field, like this

```
document.Date = date1;
```

it insert into database in this formart`2021-08-06T00:00:00.000+00:00`

please help how to fix this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to store dates in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764821/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-dates-in-mongodb)

Comment: MongoDB does not have a date data type that does not include time data as well.

Comment: my question is how to store date without time, in date format, how i can do this?

Answer (score 2):

> it insert into database in this format 2021-08-06T00:00:00.000+00:00

Actually a document like `{_id:ObjectId(), dt: Date("2021-08-06")` is inserted into the database in this format (see bsonspec.org):

```
00000000: 2200 0000 075f 6964 0061 0dd3 1dfd af14  "...._id.a......
00000010: db18 d4f9 6109 6474 0000 6cc2 187b 0100  ....a.dt..l..{..
00000020: 0000
```

The date value there is the 64-bit integer:

```
hex: 0x000017b18c26c00
decimal: 1628208000000
```

That is also the format that is returned by the MongoDB server to whatever client program you are using.

The Node.js driver recognizes that is a date type, and so helpfully deserializes that value using the `Date` constructor, such as:

```
new Date(1628208000000)
```

Try that from a REPL, and you will see that it is actually Node that is providing the format that you see:

From the mongo shell, that looks like:

```
> new Date(1628208000000)
ISODate("2021-08-06T00:00:00Z")
```

JSON doesn't have a date type, so converting will result in that value becoming string:

```
> tostrictjson({dt:new Date(1628208000000)})
{ "dt" : { "$date" : "2021-08-06T00:00:00.000-00:00" } }
```

Again, that is the client, not the database, producing the format that you see.

If you need to display the date in a particular format, use a date formatting library like Datejs, Moment.js, Luxon, etc.

Comment: @Jeo so you mean, if i want to insert the date in this format ```2021-08-07```, i need to use the moment.js etc library?

Comment: I mean MongoDB uses exactly 1 format to store dates: UTC number of milliseconds since epoch as a 64-bit integer, so you can't store "2021-08-07" as a date.  You can either give up processing that as a date and store it as a string, or you can change the display format on the client side after retrieving the value.